# Lost connection to MySQL server during Python connection

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Relatively new to Python and MySQL, but I'm performing a simple query of a DB in a dev environment using the MySQL Python Connector.  I've created a buffered cursor to return results as dictionaries.  When I perform the simple query:

family_query = ("SELECT * FROM family as FF")

...I get a list of errors, all around this idea of error 2013:  Lost Connection to MySQL server.

```
>python "FitMatch v1.5.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FitMatch v1.5.py", line 505, in <module>
    fit_match_cursor.execute(fit_family_query, () )
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 507, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 421, in _handle_result
    self._handle_resultset()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 895, in _handle_resultset
    (self._rows, eof) = self._connection.get_rows()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 671, in get_rows
    rows = self._protocol.read_text_result(self._socket, count)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 309, in read_text_result
    packet = sock.recv()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 226, in recv_plain
    raise errors.InterfaceError(errno=2013)
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I've tried increasing my connection_timeout to well over 10,000 (as I read on other stack overflow posts that could be the issue) but it had no effect.

Any ideas what could be causing the "Lost connection to MySQL server" error?

Comment: Format the errors?  Just updated with correct formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As a print of nested query result I face this problem
- my Python query would fail with the error described in the question after returning just a subset of results.
- As my way you Switched to PyMySQL and things work as you like

  [PyMySQL Link](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)
- My Sample Code For printing data

  ```
   import pymysql
   connection = pymysql.connect(user='XYZ', passwd='XYZ',host='XYZ',database='XYZ')
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   query = ("YOUR_QUERY")
   cursor.execute(query)
   for item in cursor:
       print item
  ```
- If any problem with this answer must comment me....:)

Comment: Thanks, Virbhadrasinh.  I'm hoping to not have to switch the entire codebase to PyMySQL though.  I'd rather stick to the prebuilt Python connector for MySQL since it's native to 3.x and later.

Comment: Turns out you were right, Virbhadrasinh.  After giving up, I switched out connectors and it worked fine.  Seems pretty crappy that the included Python connector for MySQL doesn't work, but oh well.  Thanks much